# Running mvn exec:java from a remote directory not containing the pom.xml

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a maven project built in '/some/where' which I wish to run/execute from another directory '/foo/bar'. I am currently running commands such as:

```
cd /some/where
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.xmlcml.cml.rest.Client
```

with

```
/some/where/pom.xml
```

I wish to do something like:

```
cd /foo/bar
mvn -p /some/where/pom.xml exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.xmlcml.cml.rest.Client
```

but don't know the syntax or whether it is allowed.

If it is allowed where are relative filenames referenced to (a) the directory containing the pom.xml , i.e. `/some/where` or (b) the current directory `/foo/bar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
mvn -f /some/where/pom.xml exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.xmlcml.cml.rest.Client
```

To find out the maven command line options:

```
mvn --help
```

---

> If it is allowed where are relative filenames referenced to (a) the directory containing the pom.xml , i.e. /some/where or (b) the current directory /foo/bar

Relative pathnames in POM file are resolved relative to the directory containing the POM.